# Laravel dependency injection

Tags: php, caching, laravel, dependency-injection

I am creating a framework agnostic composer library that employs the methodologies of DI. I am running into an issue when trying to inject laravel's Cache object as a dependency into my library class. My library class signature is as follows:

```
class Requester {
    const ACCESS_TOKEN_CACHE_KEY = 'access-token-cache-key';
    const ACCESS_TOKEN_CACHE_TTL = 36000;

    protected $clientId;

    protected $clientSecret;

    /** @var Client */
    protected $guzzleClient;

    /** @var CacheableInterface */
    protected $cache;

    /** @var string */
    protected $accessToken;

    public function __construct(
        ClientFactory $clientFactory,
        $clientId, $clientSecret,
        CacheableInterface $cache = null,
        $accessToken = null
    )
    {
        $this->guzzleClient = $clientFactory->createClient();
        $this->clientId = $clientId;
        $this->clientSecret = $clientSecret;
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->accessToken = $accessToken;
    }

    // other methods

}
```

What I would like to do is wrap Laravels cache for the driver I am using (memcache) and simply have it implement `CacheableInterface` without having to redefine all the functions that are already available through the cache driver.  Something like this:

```
class CacheWrapper extends Laravel\Cache implements CacheableInterface {

}
```

The problem I run into is when I extend `Illuminate\Cache\Repository` it wants me to redefine all of the  cache methods. Is there a way to retain the cache methods and extend the object so it implements my `CacheableInterface` or is there a better way to architect the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create something like this (of course you'd have to adjust the parameters):

```
class CacheWrapper implements CacheableInterface {

    /**
     * The laravel's driver you're using right now
     */
    private $laravelDriver;

    public function __construct(TypeHint $cacheDriver) {
        $this->laravelDriver = $cacheDriver;
    }

    /**
     * interface method
     */
    public function cacheMethod1() {
        $this->laravelDriver->analogousMethod1();
    }

    /**
     * interface method
     */
    public function cacheMethod2() {
        $this->laravelDriver->analogousMethod2();
    }

}
```